# How to solve font size problems

Tags: fonts, window

I happen to be running Kubuntu 20.04, but my question is much more general: how does one go about solving font size problems?  Obviously the first place to go is System Settings, but even there how does one know whether to change the font size, force the dpi value, or both? Or to look elsewhere instead?  And if it's necessary to force the font dpi, how do you find the right value?

But System Settings is only the start. There are also browser settings to deal with, and these may depend on the choice of browser or even the browser version.  Beyond that, there are application-specific font controls to contend with, since some apps may choose their own fonts, a choice that may or may not be overridden.

Yet another issue is the font used for window titles. That font may be, and usually  is, different
from the font used for the window contents. And of course all these questions may overlap.

I'm not expecting to find a simple answer to this question.  But consider the question to be a plea for some public-spirited Netizen to generate a How-to on the subject.

Comment: Depends on the display server. In X you can adjust the DPI setting which often had the desired result. In Wayland there should be a display magnification setting.

Comment: Your question likely is not more general: it all quite depends on the desktop environment you use.